# how to convert string and datetime value in sql

Tags: sql-server

I Have This Type Of Value

> fe80::d235:a0ce:c3ce:b764%14:2/17/2023 12:29:34 PM

and I Want this Value As 02/17/2023 Using SQL

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

try?

```sql
DECLARE @TestString VARCHAR(100)
SET @TestString='fe80::d235:a0ce:c3ce:b764%14:2/17/2023 12:29:34 PM'
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@TestString),LEN(@TestString)-CHARINDEX('/',@TestString)+3)),10),':','')
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example to convert your string into a Date.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, 'fe80::d235:a0ce:c3ce:b764%14:2/17/2023 12:29:34 PM'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS formatted_date;
```

Comment: Not working conversion error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."